# Tastypie: Creating objects outside of obj_create

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I'm a bit new to tastypie: I've been creating objects in custom views that I pass through override_urls.

Is it alright to not use obj_create and just do things in the custom views, or will this cause some trouble further down the line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You normally should use obj_create because it handles all the authorisation and authentication for you. If you use some other views (I imagine that creating new model instances should be done in some helper methods not actually views) that shouldn't be any trouble if you would follow the simple steps:

1. in your `override_urls` use the `wrap_view` method from tastypie
2. if you haven't defined a method inside your resources that actually calls the views/methods creating other objects, you should do it
3. inside the method you should in the first place use the same pattern as is being used inside tastypie's [dispatch method](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/resources.py#L452) such as is_authenticated, is_authorised and throttle_check and afterwards call your views/methods

A more simple approach would be to only override the `obj_create` inside your resources and inside this method call other views/methods, use the parent method or decide not to use it at all.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, does this mean I should differentiate all of my resources? For example, I have a User resource that handles getting existing users, as well as modifying and creating them at different overidden URLS. I assume since there can only be one obj_create that they should be spread out to different resources?

Comment: You could pass additional arguments in the request and inside obj_create decide which existing method to use, but it is up to you, I understand that there can be such special cases that wouldn't allow using obj_create.